# mean, ignore zero and specific variable

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the average of a specific set of columns, ignoring zeros and one particular column.  For example, if I run this:

```
#df
A = c(1,0,0,4,6,7)
B = c(3,2,0,6,0,10)
C = c(5,0,3,8,12,1)
D = c(22,10,45,7,9,8)
df =data.frame(A,B,C,D) 

#Mean
apply(df,1,function(x) mean(x[x>0]))
```

I get the following output:

```
[1]  7.75  6.00 24.00  6.25  9.00  6.50
```

But how can I run the same mean calculation when I include the unique id?

```
#df
A = c(1,0,0,4,6,7)
B = c(3,2,0,6,0,10)
C = c(5,0,3,8,12,1)
D = c(22,10,45,7,9,8)
unique_id = c("1A","2B","3B","1C","7F","2P")
df =data.frame(A,B,C,D,unique_id)
```

I can't subset to exclude the unique id, cause I need it to merge into other data frames.  Thanks for your help R community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compute the mean on a subset of the data frame.  Also, instead of using `apply` here you should use `rowMeans`:

```
df_sub <- df[,-which(names(df) == "unique_id")]
df$mean <- rowMeans(df_sub * (df_sub > 0), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Why we are adding , greater than zero condition in `df_sub * (df_sub > 0)` . We are getting the same result by `rowMeans(df_sub, na.rm=TRUE)` . Do we want to remove negative values.? could you please explain.

Comment: @PIG Did you see `mean(x[x>0])` in the OP?  Coincidentally, all the sample data happens to be positive, hence the possible confusion you are having.